# Remove days/hours/minutes when timer hits 00 in jQuery.countdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, countdown, jquery-countdown

I am using [jQuery.countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html) and are try to Remove days/hours/minutes when timer hits 00 with update callback function `.on('update.countdown', function(event) {`. So, almost working fine.
**but, just one issue.** It is stop on **01sec** when end of last second in last minute. So, it does not hide. why it does not 00 sec?

**I Got:** 01s

**Should be:** 00s

```
var countdown = $('.countdown[data-countdown-end]');
if (countdown.length > 0) {
    countdown.each(function() {
        var $countdown = $(this),
            finalDate = $countdown.data('countdown-end');
        $countdown.countdown(finalDate)
            .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
              var format = '<span>%-d</span> day%!d '
                  + '<span>%H</span> hr '
                  + '<span>%M</span> min '
                  + '<span>%S</span> sec';
              if(event.offset.totalDays === 0) {
                  format = '<span>%H</span> hr '
                  + '<span>%M</span> min '
                  + '<span>%S</span> sec';
              } 
              if(event.offset.totalHours === 0) {
                  format = 
                  '<span>%M</span> min '
                  + '<span>%S</span> sec';
              }
              if(event.offset.totalMinutes === 0) {
                  format = '<span>%S</span> sec';
              }
              if(event.offset.totalSeconds === 0) {
                  format = '';
              }
            $countdown.html(event.strftime(format));
    }); 
});
}
```

**Working fine without update callback function:**

if, I have used default code without update callback. So, It is stop on 00sec when end of last second in last minute.

**I Got (Fine):** 00d 00h 00m **00s**

```
var countdown = $('.countdown[data-countdown-end]');
if (countdown.length > 0) {
    countdown.each(function() {
        var $countdown = $(this),
            finalDate = $countdown.data('countdown-end');
        $countdown.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
            $countdown.html(event.strftime(
                '%Dd %Hh %Mm %Ss'
            ));
        });
    });
}
```

**Why it does not 00 sec with update callback code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got finally solution from [Advanced example](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/advanced-coupon-site.html). It is working fine with `finish` callback function.

Final working my code below:

```
var countdown = $('.countdown[data-countdown-end]');
if (countdown.length > 0) {
    countdown.each(function() {
        var $countdown = $(this),
            finalDate = $countdown.data('countdown-end');
        $countdown.countdown(finalDate)
            .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
              var format = '<span>%-d</span> day%!d '
                  + '<span>%H</span> hr '
                  + '<span>%M</span> min '
                  + '<span>%S</span> sec';
              if(event.offset.totalDays === 0) {
                  format = '<span>%H</span> hr '
                  + '<span>%M</span> min '
                  + '<span>%S</span> sec';
              } 
              if(event.offset.totalHours === 0) {
                  format = 
                  '<span>%M</span> min '
                  + '<span>%S</span> sec';
              }
              if(event.offset.totalMinutes === 0) {
                  format = '<span>%S</span> sec';
              }
            $countdown.html(event.strftime(format));
    })
   .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
        $countdown.addClass('disabled');
    });
});
}
```

Css

```
.countdown.disabled {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the code below on my site, which at the end of the count, when I delete a button as shown in the "due date", it would show another div with a message (timeout)

```js
var buy_date = new Date("DATA DO POST")
var min_max = parseInt("TEMPO DO CONTADOR")

if (min_max > 0) {
   var expire_date = new Date(new Date(buy_date).setMinutes(buy_date.getMinutes() + min_max))
  // console.log({ buy_date, expire_date })
  min_max = min_max*60

  jQuery('#clock')
    .countdown(expire_date)
    .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
      //console.log(event.offset)
      minutes = event.offset.minutes;
      hours = event.offset.hours;
      time = event.offset.totalSeconds
      var format = '%H:%M:%S';

      if (event.offset.totalDays > 0) {
        format = '%-d dias%!d ' + format;
      }
      if (event.offset.weeks > 0) {
        format = '%-w semanas%!w ' + format;
      }
      jQuery("excluircontador").attr("data-expiration", time/60 >= 10 ? Math.floor(time/60) : 10);
      jQuery(".progress-bar").css("width",  time ? 100*(min_max-time)/min_max +"%" : "100%");
      jQuery(this).html(time ? event.strftime(format) : "00:00:00");
    }).on('finish.countdown', function() {
      document.location.reload(true);
    });
}
```